# Creation of multiple nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've been struggling with this far too long now.

For the simplicity, suppose I have Lead The Jungle app in which users ask
for Recommendations to some destinations. In answer to this, other, experienced
users propose a guide man who will lead them straight to the point.

Suppose I have the following models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :destinations
  validates :username, :email
  #..
end

class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :destination
  belongs_to :guide
  #..
end


class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recommendations
  validates :name, :nickname, :phone
  #..
end

class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recommendations
  has_many :users
  #..
end
```

On my page, next to the map of the jungle I want to have single widget in which
I can propose up to three recommendations with related guide man to a single destination. I also want to
 give contact details to the guide man.

The thing is, I don't have these three recommended guides under some grouping relation (such as photos under gallery).
So I can't simply use nested attributes in this case.

Is there a way to create multiple nested objects without a single parent object containing them all?

I tried the following (among many other approaches) but guides parameter's aren't under theirs recommendations and I can't see which guide is connected to which recommendation.

```
<%= form_tag('recommendations') do -%>
   <ul id="selected-guides">
     <% @recommendations.each_with_index do |recommendation, index| %>
       <%= render 'recommendation_fields', :recommendation => recommendation} %>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

_recommendation_fields.erb

```
<%= fields_for recommendation do |Recommendation_fields| %>
  <div>
    <%= fields_for recommendation.guide do |guide_fields| %>
      <%= guide_fields.text_field :name %>
      <%= guide_fields.text_field :nickname %>
      <%= guide_fields.text_field :phone %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you may try rails 3.1 and go with a has many through assosiaction.
See the new screencast from ryan bates, it may helps you!

http://railscasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview

ryans example for a Project (models/project.rb)

```
has_many :tasks
has_many :assigments, :through => :tasks
has_many :users, :through => :assignments
```

in your case, you can access also like this, I suppose

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's the case here. Relations work fine. Or do I miss your point?